# Is there a layout in android to fit an arbitrary number of children views of varying sizes in the parent view to fit

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view

[image]

I want to acheive a look something like in this mock up but as far as i can tell there are no ways to do it without a whole new custom view. The children are going to have different sizes and they need to fit in the parent. I was looking at the gridlayout, but in the grid layout you seem to have to specify postition and size.. where the children end up in the parent view is ireelevant but their sizes are important.

Comment: Do you need the size of the children to be dynamic? Do you want the layout itself dynamic? Or is it going to look the same every time it's opened?

Comment: The children views are added dynamically and their sizes will change every time it's opened so it does not need to look the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have used RelativeLayout with nested RelativeLayouts before for something similar. It looked good, but it was not the simple, dynamic solution you are looking for.

I would look into using Canvas to give a more custom feel with more flexibility (randomness), but then you'll be working more programmatically. This gives you the ability to change their sizes whenever the app is opened.

Comment: to draw directly on the canvas? any idea how id go about making sure areas dont overlap?

Comment: So it doesn't work like a standard layout, and you'd have to come up with a creative idea to create invisible boundaries at runtime. One way would be fill the screen with randomly sized (non-overlapping) squares and then draw your circles in those squares. Or you could have set center-points for your circles, and then randomly grow each one out a certain amount until their borders are within a certain range. Unfortunately there is no simple solution for you.

Comment: [Android Canvas API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html)